# Why LINQ can't pick up the null value C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, jira, jira-rest-api

I try to use LINQ to filter the data, the data is from 3rd party API (JIRA Server), and ResolutionDateis DateTime type, I guess it use Nullable, anyway, I am pretty sure the value is null, but when I use LINQ, it just not work at all. The LINQ just can't do i.ResolutionDate == null, it always said there is no item match this condition. I'm pretty sure I have the issues their ResolutionDate  is null.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/database-issue-fields/

```
var foo = datas.Where(i =>
                i.Created > date && i.Created <= date.AddDays(7) && 
i.ResolutionDate> date.AddDays(7) && i.ResolutionDate== null);
```

Comment: What is the type of `i.ResolutionDate`?

Comment: `i.ResolutionDate` cannot simultaneously be a date more than seven days in the future and null at the same time.

Comment: should it be || instead of &&?

Comment: You're "pretty sure" that there are items with ResolutionDate that are null? Before you start wondering why LINQ doesn't work, maybe you should be completely sure.

Comment: yes, sorry the example code is incorrect, var foo = datas.Where(i =>
                i.Created > date && i.Created <= date.AddDays(7) && 
i.ResolutionDate> date.AddDays(7) || i.ResolutionDate== null); then in this case, it would become ( i.Created > date && i.Created <= date.AddDays(7) && 
i.ResolutionDate> date.AddDays(7)) or  i.ResolutionDate== null, but what I everything in the AND also include  i.ResolutionDate== null

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the value of ResolutionDate is null **OR** more than seven days in the future

```
var foo = datas.Where(i =>
                i.Created > date && i.Created <= date.AddDays(7) && 
                (i.ResolutionDate == null || i.ResolutionDate > date.AddDays(7)));
```

Comment: I want to check outstanding issue, so I want to check if the ResolutionDate is null or the ResolutionDate is after this week.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably coalesce those into `(i.ResolutionDate?.Date > date.AddDays(7))`

Ultimately, it should have some condition that will return `true` when you do the comparison.